# Is it possible to write an Android app that can sell downloaded content without using Google

Tags: android, firefox

I want to market a hardwired audio book (mini-tablet/poor man's Kindle) with downloadable content.  I am trying to decide whether to use Android or Firefox for the OS.  So before in invest a lot of time in software development I want to make sure if I choose Android for the OS that I will be able to write code to go onto my website and buy (and download) content without paying Google 30%.  So really what I am asking is this blocked in Android or does it violate their terms and conditions ?

Comment: while i understand your concern, i think you should start by taking a look at the size of the respective markets before considering how much google will take you. There are virtually no firefox devices sold yet (compared to android devices, >1B activations to date), and those that will sold will be targeting a low-end market, i.e. user without money to spend on their apps.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can publish your apk where you want, but the tax of purchase will be taken by a third party.

Links (you can publish your apk, because license what used by Android it's provides):

http://source.android.com/source/licenses.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about building a physical Android device or just an Android app?
If it's an Android device then you probably won't even have any of the Google's services installed, so definitely no 30% cut for them.

If it's an app, can your content be consumed in other medium? If yes then you are all clear, if not, then it's against Google's [Dev Policies](http://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html):

> Developers offering additional content, services or functionality
>   within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use
>   Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except:
>
> 1. where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g.,
>      buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also
>      includes a hard copy subscription);
> 2. or where payment is for digital
>      **> content or goods that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g.,
>      buying songs that can be played on other music players).**

Edit: as njzk2 mentioned, the above applies only if you wish to put your APK on Google Play. But unless you are targeting China, otherwise you simply have to publish to Google Play.

As an anecdotal note, the app we put in Taiwan's biggest operator's Android store generates about 1/200th the revenue from Google Play, and the app is mostly used by Taiwanese. While I cannot say this is the norm in every country, it's probably not the exception either.

Comment: same comment, this goes only for app distributed on Google Play

Comment: True, but it looks like he meant to purchase books from his site, not downloading app from site. Realistically speaking, unless he target China exclusively, otherwise Google Play is *the* store to put his APK if he wants to have any chance of making money. Good point though.

Comment: anyway, I think this is a none-issue. 70% of sales on google play is a zillion times more what you could get on firefox (for now)

Answer (score 0):

In Android, tax is based on your country. And using third-party payment system instead of Google IAP, violate the terms.
http://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html

Comment: precision : using third party payment system violates the terms **if you distribute your app on Google Play**